# Determine number of clusters for different datasets

Tags: cluster-analysis

I performed a clustering analysis of the media usage of different users in order to find different groups that use a specific set of media (e.g. group 1 use media A, B and C and group 2 use media B, C and D). Then I divided the datset in different groups, since the users belong to a specific group (as a consequence the original dataset and the new datasets have a different size). Within in this groups I like to cluster again which different media sets are used.
How can I determine the number of clusters to guarantee that the results are comparable?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on clustering to be stable.

It's a **hypothesis generation** tool.

You clustered, and now you have the hypothesis that there are groups ABCD of media usage. You should first evaluate if this hypothesis is adequate. Now what you want to do in your next step is to assign the labels to subsets of the data. First of all, you should be able to simply subset this from the previous labels. But if this really is different data, you can label new data, for example using the most similar record (nearest neighbor classification). But that is *classification* now, because your classes are fixed.